# how to pass parameters to the fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to pass an object to my `Fragment`. I do it like so:

```
MenuFragment fragment = new MenuFragment(item);
setFragment(fragment);
```

I know that to use a constructor with param for `Fragment`s isn't right. So I did this:

```
public static MenuFragment newInstance(String desc) {
    MenuFragment f = new MenuFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("desc", desc);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}
```

but I don't know how to pass the string and my custom object?

Comment: Which object want to pass?

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K Item item. this is my object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: if you want to pass some custom objects use

```
bundle.putSerializable(key, object)
```

method. Your object must implement `java.io.Serializable` interface.

Call then in your fragment `getArguments()` method:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup containerObject, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //...

    Bundle bundle = getArguments(); 
    Myclass itemObject  = (Myclass) bundle.getSerializable("yourKey");

    //... 
 }
```

Comment: I know myself. How did you pass  the Item object in bundle ?

Comment: @PavelPetrashov what exactly do you mean? Pass Object? Which Item object? There is no item object in your code.

Comment: I wrote a code example, as I did when passed string. Now I want to pass my object.

Comment: @ok i changed my answer. make your object serializable and use bundle.putSerializable method

Answer (score 0):

In `public void onCreate` function of the fragment, do following:

```
if (getArguments() != null) {
    String param = getArguments().getString("desc");
}
```